# Message not appear on page after function is performed in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Maybe is something simple but can't understand why I don't see my message.

I have this in the controller after the function is submitted

```
return redirect()->route('item.show', $id)->with('alert-success', ' Review submitted successfully.');
```

And this in `item` page

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info','message'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
        <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>

    @endif
@endforeach
```

The form is submitted successfully, data is saved in the database, the page is reloaded but the message does not appear for success.

update

```
array(4) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "snB4uoaR087wrvXOuh8epR56cjtC2OCSmZJd9smn"
  ["_previous"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(29) "http://example.com/item/17"
  }
  ["flash"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["old"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["new"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d"]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Route

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::post('items/review/{item}', 'ItemController@reviewSubmit')->name('item.review');

   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flash for message stuffs:

**Controller**

```
$request->flash('alert-success', ' Review submitted successfully.');
return redirect()->route('item.show', $id);
```

`item` **page**:

```
<div class="flash-message">
    @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
        @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
            <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Check about flash message with [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data)

**NOTE**: Make sure the middleware not applied twice, this is also be the cause of this issue. Check [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed?diff=split)

Comment: Thanks but I received this error `Method alert-success does not exist.`

Comment: According to docs I need `session()->` so I've made it `$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Review submitted successfully.');` but still no message on page

Comment: Outside of foreach, check into your blade `session('key')`, what it print?

Comment: Sorry the `var_dump(session('alert-success'))` is returning `NULL`

Comment: Oh, check your middleware not calling twice time, you can check your middleware and middleware group to confirm single calling

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this.

Comment: Ok, just let me know what this print `<?php echo '<pre>';var_dump(session()->all()); ?>`

Comment: I've added them to my question

Comment: I mean provide your route with group if `item.show` under any group

Comment: Because may be you applied middleware twice

Comment: added route groupd

Comment: Ok, remove `'middleware' => 'web'` from `route.php` and let me know what happen with flash message?

Comment: Yes, when I remove it the message is appeared. What can be done in this case since I need this middleware

Comment: Don't worry, from laravel 5.2.27, the web middleware is being applied in `RouteServiceProvider` to every route you register. Check [this once](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed?diff=split)

Comment: Please accept this answer for other people help.@Peter

Comment: Yes, I will. I just checked the link you provided and tested if non-logged users can access the page when I remove middleware

Comment: Ok, Also let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: So this means that I don't need to define this `'middleware' => 'web'` in my routes.php because it's automatically applied on boot?

Comment: Didn't knew this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @peter: Welcome:)